# Scale view by pan gesture

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

How can I scale the view by pan gesture?

I am facing an issue with the pinch gesture when the view is so small that I can not perform a pinch operation. Is it possible with pan gesture? Or is there any solution with pinch gesture?

I am thinking about pan gesture because we could scale by dragging from corner.

Any solution?

Comment: Are you that is shall be a pan gesture recognizer instead of [pinch](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipinchgesturerecognizer)?

Comment: yes, you are correct

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42965235/swift-3-how-do-i-pinch-to-scale-and-rotate-uiimageview https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42965235/swift-3-how-do-i-pinch-to-scale-and-rotate-uiimageview https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048581/use-uipinchgesturerecognizer-to-scale-view-in-direction-of-pinch

Comment: But they are using pinch gesture for scaling.  if view is small then there will difficulty to perform pinch gesture. because two fingers can not placed on view.

Comment: I could post an answer with using the pinch. However, I would suggest that you could double tap on the view to increase its scale...

Comment: yeah i have added double tap gesture to double the scale size. but i am thinking with pan if possible. I have seen this functionality in some apps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158953/discussion-between-jagdeep-singh-and-ahmad-f).

Comment: unfortunately I can't for now join the chat, we could comment and delete the previous ones.